# msgbox goes in Infinite loop in excelsheet

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

This code executes on worksheet_change event. It checks for duplicate mobile numbers and if found shows popup and clears particular cells value.

```
 If Target.Column = 1 Then
  r = Target.Value
  adr = Target.Address(False, False)
  LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
      For c = 2 To LastRow
          s = Sheets("Create Users").Range("A" & c).Value
          If r = s And adr <> "A" & c Then
              MsgBox ("Dupliacte phone numbers are not allowed.")
             Target.Value = ""
          End If
       Next c
  End If
```

Comment: why this is happening.It was working fine for the first time. but when i tried second time. alert msg is showing again and again infinite times........:(

Comment: Have you checked that you are not comparing two empty cells and determining that they are equal?

Comment: no i haven't checked that

Comment: but lastrow is 17, then how can go into infinite loop

Comment: Not 100% sure, but it may be looping through this routine over and over again; I'd have it kick out if `r` is empty; just to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
Target.Value = ""
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: this is working if phone number is correct.But I have applied the data validation to the phone number column. If that validation is triggered then also duplication message is getting displayed no. of times.

Comment: Data validation is used for allowing only numbers.

Comment: As you said "code executes on worksheet_change event", so, to prevent infinite loops, you must avoid that **all changes** on worksheet (made by the code called by the event) are intercepted during execution.